# how to detect if the image file exists in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of images like the following

```
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png
image4.png
…
…
image20.png



secondImg1.png
secondImg2.png
secondImg3.png
secondImg4.png
secondImg5.png
…….
……..
secondImg18.png
```

I want to load 1 image at a time dynamically.

My js

```
var index = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function(){playAnime()},200);

function playAnime(){
    $('#holder').attr('src','image/image' + index + 'png')
    index++
}
```

My codes show the general idea of how it works but I am not sure how to stop the index at 20 and 18 to stop the animation. (I could use `if` statement to check if it's 20 or 18 but I think there is a better way)

Basically, I want to detect if my app loads `image21.png and secondImg19.png` and stop because there is no such file or the image is broken. Is this doable? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can, per the link, use an ajax HEAD request, the load() event, or the error() event bindings to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**.error()**](http://api.jquery.com/error/) event handler

```
$('#holder').attr('src', 'image/image' + index + 'png').error(function () {
    //Image does not exists do something
});
```

From [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/error/)

> The error event is sent to elements, such as images, that are referenced by a document and loaded by the browser. It is called if the element was not loaded correctly.